# CornerRadius is causing toolbar buttons to not work in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swiftui

I would like show a new view with animation when clicked on the button. Using the sample code below, I noticed that if there is .cornerRadius modifier applied then the newly presented view will not have the buttons clickable, until there is some refresh like screen rotation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showNav = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    showNav.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Show")
            }
            if showNav {
                panel
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    var panel: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("In Popup")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                showNav.toggle()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text("Close")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.mint)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .background(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

So if you turn off the .cornerRadius then "Close" will be clickable, otherwise not. Is this a SwiftUI bug or something wrong here? I also noticed .shadow has the same effect, also only occurring if using transitions.

Thank you.

Comment: Working well for me, without removing `cornerRadius` from the code. Using Xcode 14.3